# HTTP Request inside a function not works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, controller, http-get

I have this controller for AngularJS Framework.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


 var locations =[]; var map; var markers = [];

$scope.mappa = function(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 37.507033, lng: 15.080257}, 
        zoom: 8
      });
}

$scope.insert = function(){

         $http.get("http://localhost:8080/SistemiDistribuiti/rest/Point/Trovati")
    .success(function(data) 
            {locations = data;});

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
             map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
     markers[i].setVisible(true);
   }
};
```

In html file, i have a button that calls the insert function.
But if I run this code, the button works at the second time only. Instead if the http request is out of the function, the button works immediatly. Why?

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/SistemiDistribuiti/rest/Point/Trovati")
.success(function(data) 
        {locations = data;});

$scope.insert = function(){

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
         map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

for (i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
 markers[i].setVisible(true); }
};
```

Comment: add the other code inside the `success` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's asynchronous method. Move the code insert into callback success.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/SistemiDistribuiti/rest/Point/Trovati")
.success(function(data) {
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0], data[i][1]),
             map: map
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setVisible(true); }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now works! But, what is a asynchronous method exactly?

Comment: @legolas07 work with "async" and "sync" in AngularJS http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2772-exploring-asynchronous-promise-based-workflows-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 3):

> But if I run this code, the button works at the second time only.

It works at the first time, it's just AJAX request is asynchronous, so the `location` variable is not populated yet by the time your are trying to use it. When you click next time, it turns out that data has already loaded and `location` is set and "cached".

You need to do your stuff in callback function:

```
$scope.insert = function () {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/SistemiDistribuiti/rest/Point/Trovati").success(function (data) {
        var marker, i, locations = data;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }       
    });

};
```

And finally, when you make it work, consider moving your request logic into reusable service, making requests in controller is not the best design:

```
$scope.insert = function () {
    locations.get().then(function(data) {
        var marker, i, locations = data;
        // ...
    });
};
```

Comment: And a directive for init Map will be very good i think. And if they are expecting a large number of positions insert markers with some kind of timeouts not to break the page. Just a sugestion. Because de answer from @dfsq is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand the second part of your reply. I moved the code into callback function and now works, but what do you mean with "And finally, when you make it work, consider moving your request logic into reusable service, making requests in controller is not the best design" ?